# Multiple matches for patterns in one token

Tags: flex-lexer

I need to count every occurence of "`ab.`", "`ba.`", "`.ab`" in some text, where "`.`" is (as usual) any character except newline.

I wrote:

```
%%

ab. counter++;
ba. counter++;
.ab counter++;

%%
```

My problem is, that for string:

```
abab
```

my counter is equal to 1 and it should be 3. It only matches "ab." (aba).
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how flex works: it consumes the characters already matched. In this specific case, it matches `ab.` on `aba`, consumes these characters, and leaves only `b` in the stream.

You could theoretically try to put back characters into the stream using the [yyless(n)](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html) macro, which returns all but the first n characters into the stream. In your case yyless(2)  (or rather yyless(yyleng-1) ) in all rules would give you the expected results.

Alternatively, you could use the `/` lookahead operator: `a/(b.)` is matched if the current character is an "a", followed by a "b" and any character, without actually consuming the anything other than the "a". It's a powerful tool, though I was always taught that the / is dangerous, and should be avoided (with the necessary logic moved to the parser).

Flex isn't really designed for this, though. You'd be better off doing it manually in any programming language.